# Regex and proper use of not

Tags: regex, r

I have the following vector of variable names:

```
vn <- c("id", "pid", "wave", "psex", "pdobd", "pdobm", "pdoby", "psat3", 
"ppa21i1", "psd23i19")
```

I am having difficulties to come up with a proper regex that removes all first p's but not the one for "pid".

```
sub(???, "", vn) ## I tried "^p[^id]?" but to no avail...
```

So, the result would look like:

```
c("id", "pid", "wave", "sex", "dobd", "dobm", "doby", "sat3", 
"pa21i1", "sd23i19")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [zero width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (negative lookahead)

```
^p(?!id)
```

Don't forget to set perl parameter to TRUE

Answer (score 4):

It is often easier to come up with the proper regular expression if you phrase your requirement in the positive: not "reject if it begins with 'p', unless it's 'pid'", but "accept if it doesn't begin with 'p', or it's 'pid'"

```
^([^p].*)|pid$
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly clumsy solution: change `pid` to `ppid`, and proceed as normal.

```
sub("^p", "", sub("^pid", "ppid", vn))
```